# Why Selenium is becoming more popular than QTP?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Recent stats from job trends:

[image]

There is a steady raise in Selenium stats from 2008, birth of Selenium WebDriver in market.
 Suggest your views and ideas on this... So that the future generation will learn from you.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of reason. To name a few -

1. Selenium is an OpenSource Tool [Free].
2. Selenium has a very active community for support and updates.
3. Selenium gives you freedom of choosing programming language.
4. Selenium can be used in any OS environment (If I am not wrong QTP is limited to Windows)
5. You can use selenium with any IDE of your choice.
6. Large array of drivers (browsers like IE, FF, etc even Android and all)
7. Again because it is FOSS. Free and very active community.

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774255/qtp-vs-selenium-compare?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is also fair to say that Selenium is very light-weight and developer-friendly.  You can easily integrate with existing unit testing tools in the same language in use by developers.  Tests can be executed quickly and provide immediate feedback.  You can even run multiple tests concurrently on the same machine, where QTP only lets you run one test at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Every tool has it's pros and cons; And even Selenium has cons. But, what makes it better than QTP is:

- Open source
- Highly Extensible (Vast varieties of add-ons)
- Supports various operating systems
- Can run tests across different browsers